# Trouble with Keras ImageDataGenerator .flow()

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, data-augmentation

I was writing down some lines to implement an image data augmentation step im my galaxy image ML classification project. I have a dataset of N images of format (300x300x3). I chose the `Tf.keras ImageDataGenerator` API but I suspect I have some problems with `.flow()` method.

my wish is to generate for each image of the dataset, for example, exactly 1 vertical flip, 1 horizontal flip, 1 rotation; so for N images I expect to have 3xN augmented images.

Then I want to make a plot on several lines, the original images on the first one and the augmented ones on the following ones and here the problems arise.
when I go to plot, I realize that the transformations have not all been performed.

For simplicity, I did a test on 4 images with only one horizontal flip and I didn't find the expected results.

here did i go wrong?

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data_gen = ImageDataGenerator(horizontal_flip=True)

input_images = img_0 # load_images() 

# Aggiungi una dimensione di batch all'array di immagini
#input_images = np.expand_dims(input_images, axis=0) 

# Genera le immagini aumentate
augmented_images = data_gen.flow(input_images,
                                 batch_size=1,
                                 shuffle=False)

# Recupera le immagini flippate generate
flipped_images = augmented_images.__next__()#[0]  # Utilizza __next__() per ottenere il prossimo elemento
#flipped_images = flipped_images.reshape((300,300,3))

# Stampa le immagini originali e quelle flippate
num_images = input_images.shape[0]
print(num_images)
print(f"numero di augmented_images {augmented_images[0].shape}")
print(f"dimensioni di flipped_images {flipped_images.shape}")
print(f"dimensioni di flipped_images[0] {flipped_images[0].shape}")
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, num_images, figsize=(10, 4))



for i in range(num_images):
    axes[0, i].imshow(input_images[ i])
    axes[0, i].set_title('Immagine originale')

    # Recupera le immagini flippate generate
    #flipped_images = augmented_images.__next__()  # Utilizza __next__() per ottenere il prossimo elemento

    axes[1, i].imshow(flipped_images.reshape((300,300,3)))
    axes[1, i].set_title('Immagine flippata')
    flipped_images = augmented_images.__next__()#[0]

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```